# Problema con CONSULTA SQL y inner joins

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, mysql-workbench

Hola tengo esta consulta que me da este error
**Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'a.id_alumno' in 'field list'    0.000 sec**

Esta es la consulta

```
SELECT a.id_alumno, 
avg(asi.asistencia) as porcentaje,
asig.id_asignacion,
count(asi.id_asistencia) as total, a.ape_pat_alumno, a.ape_mat_alumno, a.nombre_alumno, a.no_control_tsu, a.no_control_lic,nombre_materia, hm.id_estatus, 
g.nombre FROM alumno 
inner join asistencia asi on asi.id_alumno=a.id_alumno
inner join unidad_materia u on u.id_unidad=asi.id_planeacion
inner join asignacion_grupal asig on asig.id_asignacion=u.id_asignacion
inner join grupo g on asig.id_grupo=g.id_grupo
inner join cuatrimestre c on c.id_cuatrimestre=g.id_cuatrimestre
inner join programa_materia pm on pm.id_pro_materia = asig.id_pro_materia
inner  join materia m on m.id_materia = pm.id_materia
inner  join ultimo_historial uh on uh.id_alumno = a.id_alumno
inner  join historial_administrativo hm on hm.id_historial = uh.id_historial
where c.id_cuatrimestre =14 
group by asi.id_alumno,asig.id_asignacion
HAVING avg(asi.asistencia)< 1.7;
```

Comment: Pareciera que te falta el alias `FROM alumno  a`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te falta ponerle el alias a alumno

```
FROM alumno a
```

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo!